# Oracle does not use invisible index despite of hint

Tags: oracle, indexing, oracle12c, hint

I seem to be messing up the index hint syntax but I've tried every schema/table/index-combination I can think of.

The table as well as the index are in a different schema than the SYS user (which is the user I am testing the index hint with)

This is the statement without the hint

```
select id from car.event where dat < sysdate and type != 0
```

These are the ways I tried to implement the index hint for the index `dat_type` in the `car` schema

```
select /*+ index(car.event car.dat_type) */ id from car.event where dat < sysdate and type != 0
select /*+ index(event car.dat_type) */ id from car.event where dat < sysdate and type != 0
select /*+ index(car.event dat_type) */ id from car.event where dat < sysdate and type != 0
select /*+ index(event dat_type) */ id from car.event where dat < sysdate and type != 0
select /*+ index(event (dat, type)) */ id from car.event where dat < sysdate and type != 0
```

So for these five statements I looked up my five different sql_ids and took a look at the execution plans like so

```
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_awr([sql_id]));
```

But none of them shows the usage of the index. All of them use a DoP of 20. Do I have to explicitely disable parallelism for the use of the index? Or can anybody please correct the syntax of my index hint?

This is the definition of the `dat_type` index

```
create index car.dat_type on car.event(dat, type) online;
```

---

Edit: The index is set to invisible, so that other statements cannot use the index but I want to use it explicitly with the index hint. In my understanding the invisibility should not be a problem for the index hint. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: What optimizer mode is set for Oracle query optimizer ?

Comment: optimizer_mode is set to ALL_ROWS

Comment: Suggest maybe you modify your question title to specific "invisible index", since that turns out to be an important factor.

Comment: @DaveCosta thanks, did that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I stumbled upon [this article](https://antognini.ch/2008/11/invisible-indexes-and-hints/) which indicates that it should in fact not be possible to use invisible indexes with just an index hint. However, invisible indexes can be used with the additional hint `USE_INVISIBLE_INDEXES`.

So this is how I got it to work:

```
select /*+ use_invisible_indexes index(car dat_type) */ id from car.event where dat < sysdate and type != 0
```

Comment: nice one - didn't know that

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to choose the ID column in your examples.  You have to specify the schema name and the index without the schema "dot".

You can do:

```
select /*+ index(car dat_type) */ id from car.event where dat < sysdate and type != 0
```

or

```
select /*+ index(car, dat_type) */ id from car.event where dat < sysdate and type != 0
```

This does NOT always force the index, but getting the syntax right is a good start.  Sometimes the Cost Based Optimizer (CBO) is stubborn...

Comment: Of course I specified the id column in the select part. Sorry, this was a mistake from pseudomizing the statement. I corrected it in my original question. Thanks for the hint with the schema dot, I'm trying this now.

Comment: That doesn't match the index hint syntax as I understand it.  The first argument should be the tablespace, not the schema name.  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10752/hintsref.htm#5156

Comment: I typo'd in my comment - nonetheless, a schema name by itself is hardly enough to specify a table.

Comment: Optimizer still uses DoP 20 and no index

Comment: It was not me who downvoted your answer. I just upvoted it because it pointed me to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have not really used invisible indexes, but my reading of the documentation indicates that a hint alone will not enable their use.  You must use an initialization parameter at the system or session level:

> An invisible index is an index that is ignored by the optimizer unless
>   you explicitly set the OPTIMIZER_USE_INVISIBLE_INDEXES initialization
>   parameter to TRUE at the session or system level.

(from https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/indexes003.htm#ADMIN12317)

Based on my testing with a *visible* index, either of these options in the hint work as expected:

```
/*+ index(event) */
/*+ index(event dat_type) */
```

Possibly other alternatives would work as well, but these are the simplest and they work fine.  The problem is not in your index hint syntax; it is that you need another step to enable the use of an invisible index.

**Edited to add**: as the OP found, another way to enable the use of invisible indexes is the USE_INVISIBLE_INDEX hint. To accomplish what the OP wants with hints only, both the USE_INVISIBLE_INDEX hint and the INDEX hint must be specified.

Comment: The documentation says for OPTIMIZER_USE_INVISIBLE_INDEXES = TRUE: "Invisible indexes are treated as visible (normal) indexes." [Source](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-8816DFA5-3D98-41DD-B752-D384BC8DE12A.htm#REFRN10301) but I don't want that. I want the invisible index to be used with the index hint which I think should be possible

Comment: But ... why do you think that is/should be possible?  I see nothing in the documentation to indicate that is the case.

Comment: Good question .. I thought I read it somewhere .. but I just now found [this](https://antognini.ch/2008/11/invisible-indexes-and-hints/) and together with the USE_INVISIBLE_INDEXES hint my index hint works on invisible indexes.

Comment: It was not me who downvoted your answer. I just upvoted it because it pointed me to the solution.